# Java JDBC SQL Server database keeps freezing

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc

So I have recently been working on a web-app which is connected to a SQL server database. During testing everything went fine; all methods work and there were no major issues. At a certain point in the testing-phase I left the server on for more extended amounts of time and after a while of usage the server starts freezing...

I have narrowed down the cause of the problem to the point where it is trying to make connections with the database. It seems to be stuck there and this prevents the server from sending a response to the client (the person using the web-app). In turn, the client is waiting eternally to get a response from the server.

The only thing that crosses my mind that could cause this, is that not all connections are being closed properly. However, I close (in order) all of my ResultSets, PreparedStatements and Connections. I also track how many connections there are through a integer variabele, and I check the amount of connections through SQL Server Management Studio and neither show a leakage in the amount of connections. The code below shows the class I use for DB communication;

```
package core;

import core.tables.Accounts;
import core.tables.Diseases;
import core.tables.PatientTable;
import core.tables.ResearchTypes;
import core.tables.Researches;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import users.Patient;
import users.Researcher;
import users.User;

/**
 * This class provides the connection towards a database. All communication with
 * the database should be done through this class.
 * @author Wessel Jongkind
 * @version 05-07-2017
 */
public class DatabaseConnection
{
    /**
     * The connection to the database.
     */
    private Connection connection;

    /**
     * This ArrayList is used as a temporary storage for all executed PreparedStatements.
     * Those will be closed once the commit() or closeConnection() methods are called.
     * This is required to avoid memory leaks and to make sure that all channels are closed
     * properly.
     */
    private final ArrayList<PreparedStatement> statements = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * This ArrayList is used as a temporary storage for all ResultSets.
     * Those will be closed once the commit() or closeConnection() methods are called.
     * This is required to avoid memory leaks and to make sure that all channels are closed
     * properly.
     */
    private final ArrayList<ResultSet> resultsets = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * The amount of connections that are currently alive.
     */
    private static int connections = 0;

    /**
     * The default error to be send by this class when something goes wrong.
     */
    private static final String DEFAULT_ERROR = "The transaction with the database has failed. ";


    public DatabaseConnection(Connection connection) throws Exception
    {
        this.connection = openConnection(connection);
        System.out.println(connections);
    }

    public void commit() throws Exception
    {
        try{
            connection.commit();
            closeConnection();
        }catch(Exception e){
            closeConnection();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public ResultSet executeStatement(String theStatement, ArrayList<String> values) throws Exception
    {
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(theStatement);
        statements.add(statement);
        try{

            //Fill in the parameters of the SQL statement
            for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
                statement.setString(i + 1, values.get(i));

            statement.execute();
            ResultSet rs =  statement.getResultSet();
            resultsets.add(rs);

            return rs;
        }catch(Exception e){
            closeConnection();
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception(DEFAULT_ERROR + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public int getConnectionCount()
    {
        return connections;
    }

    private Connection openConnection(Connection connection) throws Exception
    {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE);
        connections++;
        return connection;
    }

    public void closeConnection()
    {
        try{
            closeResultSets();
            closeStatements();

            if(!connection.isClosed())
                connections--;
            connection.close();

            System.out.println(connections);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closeResultSets()
    {
        for(ResultSet rs : resultsets)
        {
            try{
                if(rs != null)
                    rs.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    private void closeStatements()
    {
        for(PreparedStatement statement : statements)
        {
            try{
                if(statement != null)
                    statement.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use Apache Tomcat to deploy the application. The database is connected to through a @Resource annonation. The context.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/Hart4Onderzoek">
<Resource auth="Container" 
          driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
          logAbandoned="true"
          maxActive="8"
          maxIdle="4"
          name="jdbc/H4O" 
          password="secret" 
          removeAbandoned="true" 
          removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          url="jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-PS13CKQ;databaseName=H4O;integratedSecurity=true"
          username="DESKTOP-PS13CKQ\MemeMeister"/>
</Context>
```

It would be awesome if someone could push me in the right direction. I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working.

**Edit 1**
For some reason it randomly happens once in a while that a connection does not close down. In the java-app it registers that it has executed the closeConnection() method, but in SSMS it shows that more connections are open than that is expected after this closeConnection() operation. However, I receive no thrown exceptions when I run the closeConnection() method...

**Edit 2**
The amount of connections that aren't closed seems to hang around 3-4 and does not increase from that point.

**Edit 3**
The freeze only seems to occur once I deploy the .war file in Apache Tomcat. When launching the project from Netbeans the problem does not occur.

**Edit 4**
Classes that use the DatabaseConnection class use it as follows:

```
DatabaseConnection connection = null;
try{
    connection = getDatabase();
    //some more code
    connection.commit();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    defaultExceptionHandling(connection, response, e, getSession(request));
} finally {
    if(connection != null) connection.closeConnection();
}
```

The method defaultExceptionHandling is as follows:

```
public void defaultExceptionHandling(DatabaseConnection connection, HttpServletResponse response, 
                                     Exception e, Session session) throws  ServletException, IOException
{
    //some code

    if(connection != null)
        connection.closeConnection();

    //Some more code
}
```

Comment: I see a lot of issues with you exception manage, not enough `finally` statement to be sure some code will be executed. You catch `Exception` which means everything, so you could have a bug that you missed, leaving the `connection` open.

Comment: @AxelH The connections aren't closed instantly by this class. They are closed by classes that use the class above, and I've checked all of them several times: they close their connections. What I did notice is this: For some reason it randomly happens once in a while that a connection does not close down. In the java-app it registers that it has executed the closeConnection() method, but in SSMS it shows that more connections are open than that is expected.

Comment: Try to catch Throwable instead of Exception